# Where I can find pdfkit or wkhtmltopdf logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm trying to debug issue with error on pdf generation in Ruby on Rails app. I'm using the pdfkit + wkhtmltopdf-binnary gems. Because of some issue I'm receiving the 500 and this info in logs:

`RuntimeError (command failed (exitstatus=1): /home/ubuntu/phys-track/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf --quiet --page-size Letter --margin-top 0.75in --margin-right 0.75in --margin-bottom 0.75in --margin-left 0.75in --encoding UTF-8 - -):`

I'm wondering where I can find any log where I can see any more verbose information about the issue.

Comment: I doubt they keep logs. since they're command-line apps, they'd probably just spit out errors to stderr

Comment: The part you should try and remove is the `--quiet` in the command line. This will output lots more output and let you figure out where things are going wrong. Also, if you see a `Killed` in that output, check your computer's resources when that happens - you're likely running out of Memory/Swap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try set verbose to true in PDFKit configuration.. for example, you may have config/application.rb file to be like this

```
require 'pdfkit'
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  # other options here
  config.verbose = true #to turn off --quiet mode
end
```

you can refer to https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/blob/master/spec/pdfkit_spec.rb for configuration examples